# Python: Shorten If / Elif control flow tree (printing highest order string that is not None)

Tags: python

In Python, I'm going to write a bunch of rules that prints out the "highest order" in a tree hierarchy.

`level_1` is the lowest and `level_3` is the highest order.

The "highest order" available should be printed. Only if `level_3` is `None`, do we continue to test to print `level_2`, and so forth.

```
level_1 = "Trunk"
level_2 = "Branch"
level_3 = "Leaf"

if level_3 is not None:
    print level_3

elif level_2 is not None:
    print level_2

elif level_1 is not None:
    print level_1

>>> "Leaf"
```

Question:

Is there a way that this code can be simplified in Python? Ideally to as few rows as possible.

Whereby I mean, **shortening the code length**. *(The issue is not deployment of the code for different cases, because it can be put in a function and used many times over).*

Comment: Is the explicit check against `None` fully intended?

Comment: In your above example, change the third line to `level_3 = ''` (empty string). What should be printed now?

Comment: Okay, so the `None` check is intended, okay :)

Comment: @poke Yes, it's intended.

Comment: Btw, I apologize if "highest order" here is really what's known as "lowest order" in Network theory – assuming that *level 1* is the "trunk". Tried to Google but couldn't find good definitions at a glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
for msj in (level_3,level_2,level_1):
    if msj:
        print msj
        break
```

or a variation to Reut solution

```
msj = level_3 or level_2 or level_1
if msj:
    print msj
```

both solution will print the first non-empty and non-None element they come across

Answer (score 2):

Assuming no string is empty, you can use `or`:

```
print level_3 or level_2 or level_1
```

This will work for any collection of none-empty strings since `or` returns the last truthy value.

Comment: Note that this works based on the truthness of those values, so if the explicit check against `None` was required, this will not be an equivalent replacement.

Comment: This is equivalent to the deterministic input presented, and generally to any none-empty string collection.

Comment: As OP now clarified, the explicit check against `None` is required, so this solution will not fit OP’s requirement (hence my original comment).

Comment: The fact this code is structured in statements and the values are known in advance do not support your claim. It deterministically works. It *may* not work when there is something that is tagged as an empty string (depends on the expected output), but that seems to be **practically** irrelevant. Furthermore, it will have to be **manually** added to the statement since, again, the logic here is structured.

Answer (score 0):

If you insert in correct order (something like a heap) the rules in an array, it would be easy to get the highest one.